# Override conforming to protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, swift-protocols

I installed a Pod `Material` and that pod has something like this:

```
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    //here is the method to conform protocol
}
```

But I need my own conforming to that protocol in the same place:

When I try to extend my `UIViewController` with `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` then I got an error:

> redundant conformance to protocol.

What I need to do?

```
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    //my OWN implementation here I need
}
```

**Is there a way to override conformance from Pod with my own?**

Comment: Your superclass has already confirming protocol

Comment: It is not an answer to the question.:) sorry

Comment: You don't need to add the protocol to the extension if it is already implemented by the class. And you can't override a method in an extension your best bet is to subclass the class Pod and override the method in the subclass

Comment: No, you do not understand. I DO NOT WANT to even use a class from pod... But it is implemented... I need to do this for every controller in my app, but on my own rules...

Comment: You can still try to `override` the function from the delegate, without trying to declare the extension. If it's not `override`en in an extension, you should be able to override it. And if you can, then you can separate it out to an extension as well.

Comment: I could not override because I do not subclass it

Comment: Don't you think that this protocol is implemented in this pod for a reason, and by overriding this implementation without calling super you might break the way your external library works?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I know this is not answer , it is just info. however you can use  protocol methods without confirming it anywhere , in all subclass of UIViewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found that worked is to create a separate BaseController class that is just a subclass of UIViewController

```
import UIKit
class BaseController: UIViewController {

}
```

That is placed in a file alone that does not import Material.
And all the UIViewControllers that you want to override the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate in should be a subclass of it.

```
import UIKit
import Material
class ViewController: BaseController {

}
```

This will make it compile

```
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

It is not the most optimal solution but it works

Edit: This will allow you to use Material elements like the textfields and such while having you retain the default functionality of the UIViewController without the additions found in the library